# Redirect >> domain.com/test to another url (domain.com/test3 using .htaccess (wp)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I am trying to redirect one complete URL

```
But this is not working ...
```

Comment: Your RewriteCond will never match, because `https://www.moccioso.com/d.php? 
id=ultimateselection.zip` is not a host name.

Comment: What is the best solution to help me achieve this? From your point of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www.moccioso.com/d.php? 
> id=ultimateselection.zip$ 
> RewriteRule ^$ http://moccioso.com/sd_product/ultimateselection-zip 
> [L,R=301]
> ```

(I'm assuming you've not wrapped the code onto multiple lines in your actual code?)

The `HTTP_HOST` variable contains the `Host` HTTP request header. ie. the *hostname* specified on the request eg. `www.example.com` only - there is no scheme, URL-path or query string here. So, this `RewriteCond` directive will never match.

But you are also trying to match an empty URL-path with the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^$` - so again, this will never match. In your example the URL-path is `/d.php`. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only.

You are also redirecting to `http` (not `https`) in this directive? Your example uses `https`. You are also removing the `www` subdomain, but again, your example includes it?

If you are redirecting from/to the same hostname and only have one domain then you don't need to explicitly include the domain name (ie. the requested hostname) in the rule.

To match against the query string you need to match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

Try the following instead, near the *top* of your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=ultimateselection\.zip$ 
RewriteRule ^d\.php$ /sd_product/ultimateselection-zip [R=301,L]
```

This will need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file. Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Clear your browser cache before testing.